# ajax callback on form element checkboxes

Tags: forms, ajax

I am having some troubles with ajax on form element checkboxes, in ajax callback form_state is without values and triggering element etc .. why is that?

The form is called with drupal_get_form and this is my element

```
$form['select_options'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkboxes',
  '#options' => $options, 
  '#ajax' => array(
    'callback' => 'ajax_options_callback',
    'wrapper' => 'options-form',
    'event' => 'change',
    'method' => 'replace',
  ),
);
```

Comment: If `$form_state['input']` there? and maybe you have set limit validation errors somehow?

Comment: Please also share the code for ajax_options_callback function.

Comment: you haven't used default value this ajax, so when form will postback on ajax this will reset all fields on that page.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a callback `$forms` and `$form_state` is available for use in your callback. But you should call them as parameters in your callback definition.
So:

```
public function ajax_option_callback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  // get the id of the form
  $value = $form_state->getFormObject()->getFormId();
  // create a response object and return it
}

public function ajax_option_callback() {
  // $form and $form_state not available
}
```

Note that `&form_state->getTriggeringElement()` contains nothing as the form is not submitted.

I realize now the question is for D7. Maybe my answer is usefull for someone within the D8 context.

Comment: As the author mentioned that the form is called with `drupal_get_form`. So he is seeking for answer in Drupal 7.